# Usage Scenarios for Auto Encoders as alternatives to PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, autoencoders

Is there ever a practical situation where one would use a linear autoencoder over PCA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What're the differences between PCA and autoencoder?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120080/whatre-the-differences-between-pca-and-autoencoder)

Comment: Thanks @vigos. I think the two questions are close enough